# React Native setState Flickering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have something very simple to do, which I have done before, and now doesn't seem to work. I just need a number to go up once every second and then display it.
Here is my code:

```
const counter = () => {

    let i: number = 0
    setInterval(() => {
        i += 1
    }, 1000)

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
    setInterval(() => { setNumber(i) }, 1000)

    return (
        <Text>{number}</Text>
    )
}
```

This is very simple and yet doesn't work. What happens is that the number flickers, going between numbers up and down as it slowly climbs up the number line. It's... not great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistakes: first of all don't call `setInterval` in component's body (you don't know how many times will be called). Use an `useEffect` (that runs 1 time at component's loading) to init the `setInterval` and use `prev` value in `setNumber` to get the prevoius value of `number` and increment it by one:

```
const counter = () => {

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
       setInterval(() => { setNumber(prev => prev + 1) }, 1000)
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <Text>{number}</Text>
    )
}
```

Now if you want to clear the `setInterval` on component's unmounting, use `return` in `useEffect`:

```
const counter = () => {

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
    let myInterval = null;

    useEffect(() => {
       myInterval = setInterval(() => { setNumber(prev => prev + 1) }, 1000);

       return () => {
          if (myInterval) clearInterval(myInterval);
       }
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <Text>{number}</Text>
    )
}
```

This is the cleanest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems I see in this solution which might be causing flicker issue.

1. Using two `setInterval`s
2. Updating state without using prev State

Counter component should be like below.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setNumber(number => number + 1);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => {
      cancelInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <View>{number}</View>;
};
```